# como llamar un procedimiento almacenado mysql desde php con datos de un form

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedure

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
include 'MenuNav.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="../Resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Aplicacion Web</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Resources/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <title>Registro de Embarazadas</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2 align ="center">Ingresar Nueva Embarazada</h2>

        <div class='container'> 
            <form class='form-horizontal' name='regEmb' id="regEmb">
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <div class='col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10'>
                        <table class='table table-striped' align="center" id="tablaReg">
                            <tr><td>Id Embarazada</td><td><input type ='text' name='idEmbarazada' id='idEmbarazada' value='0' readonly/></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 1</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita1' id='visita1' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Nombre de la Embarazada</td><td><input type ='text' name='nombreEmb' id='nombreEmb' required /></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 2</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita2' id='visita2' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td >Edad: </td><td><input type ='number' min='10' max='52' name='edad' step='1' id='edad' required/></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 3</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita3' id='visita3' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td >Expediente: </td><td><input type ='text' name='Expediente' id='Expediente' /></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 4</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita4' id='visita4' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td >Canton :</td><td><select name='idCanton' id='idCanton'>
                                        <option value=1>El Faro</option>
                                        <option value=2>Col. Bellos Horizontes</option>
                                        <option value=3>La Shila</option>
                                        <option value=4>Los Conacastes</option>
                                        <option value=6>El Penon</option>
                                        <option value=7>El Matazano</option>
                                        <option value=8>El Rosario</option>
                                        <option value=9>Zona A Urbana</option>
                                        <option value=10>Zona B Urbana</option>
                                        <option value=11>San Antonio</option>
                                        <option value=12>Col. Venezuela</option>
                                        <option value=13>San Luis II</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 5</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita5' id='visita5' /></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Fecha de Inscripcion</td><td><input type ='date' name='fechaInscripcion' id='fechaInscripcion'/></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 6</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita6' id='visita6'  /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Riesgo: </td><td><input type ='text' name='riesgo' id='riesgo' required /></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 7</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita7' id='visita7' /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr><td>Fecha Ultima Regla</td><td><input type ='date' name='fur' id='fur'/></td>
                                <td>Fecha Visita 8</td><td><input type ='date' name='visita8' id='visita8' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Fecha Probable de parto</td><td><input type ='date' name='fpp' id='fpp' /></td>
                                <td>Fecha Fracaso del Parto</br></br>Edad gestacional al fracaso</td><td><input type ='date' name='fechaFracaso' id='fechaFracaso' />
                                    </br><input type ='number' min='0' max='42' step='1' name='edadgesFracaso'   id='edadgesFracaso' value='0' /></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Formula Obstetrica</td><td>
                                    G:<input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='gravida' id='gravida' value='0' required/>
                                    P:<input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='paridad' id='paridad' value='0' />
                                    P:<input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='prematuro' id='prematuro' value='0' /></br></br>
                                    A:<input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='aborto' id='aborto' value='0' />
                                    V:<input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='vive' id='vive' value='0' /></td>
                                <td>Fecha  Parto </br></br>Lugar del parto:</td><td><input type ='date' name='parto' id='parto'/></br><input type ='text' name='lugarParto' id='lugarPartp'/></td>


                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Inscripcion Odontologia</td><td><input type ='date' name='insodontologia' id='insodontologia'/></td>
                                <td>Complicacion en el parto: </td><td><input type ='text' name='complicacionParto' id='complicacionParto' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>UCSF Responsable: </td><td> <select name='idUCSF' id='idUCSF' required> <option value="">seleccion UCSF</option> <option value='1'>UCSF La Shila</option>  <option value='2'>UCSF El Conacaste</option><option value='3'>UCSF El Matazano</option> <option value='4'>UCSF Intermedia Comasagua</option><option value='5'>UCSF Talnique</option></select></td>
                                <td>Fecha  Inscripcion de la Puerpera</td><td><input type ='date' name='FechaInsPP' id='FechaInsPP' /></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr><td>Promotor Responsable:</td><td><select name='idPromotor' id='idPromotor' required>
                                        <option value="">seleccion Promotor de Salud</option>
                                        <option value=1>Jorge Antonio Gonzalez</option>
                                        <option value=2>Maria Carlota Reyes Perez</option>
                                        <option value=3>Carlos Antonio Valladares </option>
                                        <option value=4>Maira Guadalupe Hernandez</option>
                                        <option value=5>Rafael Antonio Escobar</option>
                                        <option value=6>Jaquelin Nohemy Amaya Dominguez</option>
                                        <option value=7>Flor Maria Jacobo</option>
                                        <option value=8>Bill Alexander Gonzalez Reales</option>
                                        <option value=9>Diana Stephany Linares Fuentes</option>
                                        <option value=10>Iris Iveth Pacheco</option>
                                        <option value=11>Jose Ricardo Cornejo</option>
                                        <option value=12>Gerson Ulises Cortez Martinez</option>
                                        <option value=13>Mauricio Ernesto Umana Iraheta</option>
                                        <option value=14>Erazmo Escobar</option>
                                    </select></td>
                                <td>Fecha Inscripcion del recien nacido  </td><td><input type ='date' name='fechaInsRN' id='fechaInsRN' /></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr><td>Observaciones : </td><td><textarea rows='3' cols='30' name='observaciones' id='observaciones' ></textarea></td>
                                <td>Complicaciones del Recien nacido:</td><td><input type ='number' min='0' max='18' step='1' name='complicacionRN' id='complicacionRN' value='0' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="4" align="center"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="ingresar">Guardar</button>
                                </td></tr>

                        </table>

                    </div></div> 
            </form>
        </div>
  <script src="../Resources/js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Resources/js/embarazadas.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi método en el Modelo

```
function ingresar($idEmbarazada, $nombreEmb, $edad, $Expediente, $idCanton,     
$fechaInscripcion, $riesgo, $fur, $fpp, $gravida, $paridad, $prematuro, $aborto, $vive, 
$visita1, $visita2, $visita3, $visita4, $visita5, $visita6, $visita7, $visita8, 
$fechaFracaso, $edadgesFracaso, $parto, $lugarParto, $complicacionParto, $FechaInsPP, 
$fechaInsRN, $complicacionRN, $insodontologia, $observaciones, $idUCSF, $idPromotor)
{
    $sql = "insert into embarazadas(nombreEmb, edad, Expediente, idCanton, fechaInscripcion, 
    riesgo, fur, fpp, gravida, paridad, prematuro, aborto, vive, visita1, visita2, visita3, 
    visita4, visita5, visita6, visita7, visita8, fechaFracaso, edadgesFracaso, parto, 
    lugarParto, complicacionParto, FechaInsPP, fechaInsRN, complicacionRN, 
    insodontologia, observaciones, IdUCSF, idPromotor) 
    VALUES ('$nombreEmb','$edad','$Expediente',$idCanton,'$fechaInscripcion','$riesgo',
    '$fur','$fpp','$gravida','$paridad','$prematuro','$aborto','$vive','$visita1',
    '$visita2','$visita3','$visita4','$visita5','$visita6','$visita7','$visita8',
    '$fechaFracaso','$edadgesFracaso','$parto','$lugarParto','$complicacionParto',
    '$FechaInsPP','$fechaInsRN','$complicacionRN','$insodontologia','$observaciones',
    '$idUCSF','$idPromotor')";
    if ($this->conexion->conexion->query($sql)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }

    $this->conexion->cerrar();
}
```

y este el controlador que recibe los parámetros.

¿Cómo cambio la sentencia `insert into` por el el procedimiento almacenado que se llama `SP_insertEMB` en mi BD?

Answer (score 1):

Tenes que usar la sentencia de SQL `CALL` para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado.

```
$sql = "CALL procedimientoAlmacenado();";
```

En tu caso, sería de la siguiente manera:

```
$sql = "CALL SP_insertEMB( $nombre, $edad );";
```

Además, es una buena práctica el uso de las sentencias preparadas para evitar la inyección SQL.

```
$nombre = "Maria";
$edad = 25;
$stmt = $db->prepare("CALL SP_insertEMB (?, ?);");
$stmt->bind_param("si", $nombre, $edad);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$db->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma también sería la siguiente:
Para cambiar la sentencia, creas una función, y le envías los parámetros que necesites, y desde ahí llamas al procedimiento almacenado. (El procedure en la BD tiene que estar preparado para recibir e insertar todos los parámetros que le estas enviando).

Te quedaría así en php.

```
    public function executInsert($nombreEmb, $edad, $Expediente){
    try{
    //Declaras parámetros de salida
    $sentencia = $this->db->prepare("CALL SP_insertEMB(?, ?, ?);");
    $sentencia->bindParam("1", $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $sentencia->bindParam("2", $tlfn, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000); 
    $sentencia->bindParam("3", $email_cliente, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);  

    // llamar al procedimiento almacenado
    $sentencia->execute();

    //print "El procedimiento contiene: $nombreEmb, $edad, $Expediente;

    return true;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;
    }
```